# What software can I use to self-assess my own Elo rating?

Tags: software, fide, rating

What software (preferably free) can I use to do a self assessment to determine my own Elo rating?

Answer (score 5):

Googling "[Elo chess rating](http://www.google.com/search?q=ELO+Chess+Rating)" provides a [good answer](http://www.chessmaniac.com/ELORating/ELO_Chess_Rating.shtml), though it does not give any insight into what good answers are, or at least how that page is scoring answers:

- **Question 1:** blank=1000; f6,f3=2600; c5,d4=1900; c6,d4=1900; b4,c3=1400; c8,a6=1500; f6,g6=1400; e6,e5=1200; c8,d7=1600
- **Question 2:** blank=1000; g2,e4=2600; g5,h7=1950; h5,g6=1900; g2,f1=1400; g2,d5=1200; f2,f4=1400
- **Question 3:** blank=1000; c5,c6=2500; g3,g6=2000; e4,e5=1900; g3,g5=1700; e4,d4=1200; d6,e5=1200
- **Question 4:** blank=1000; e5,e6=2500; b3,f7=1600; b3,c2=1700; b3,d1=1800
- **Question 5:** blank=1000; e3,c5=2500; f5,h6=2100; e3,h6=1900; f5,g7=1500; f2,g3=1750; c8,f8=1200; f2,h4=1200; e3,b6=1750; e2,c4=1400
- **Question 6:** blank=1000; g5,f6=2500; c3,d5=1700; c4,b5=1900; f2,f4=1700; a2,a3=1200; e1,e3=1200
- **Question 7:** blank=1000; f6,h7=2500; f6,e4=1800; g6,g5=1700; a6,a5=1700; g8,h7=1500
- **Question 8:** blank=1000; b6,d8=2500; c8,e8=1600
- **Question 9:** blank=1000; e3,d4=2500; e4,g6=1800; e4,h7=1800; e3,h6=1700; d7,b7=1400
- **Question 10:** blank=1000; d8,d7=2600; f6,e8=2000; h7,h5=1800; c5,d4=1600; c8,a6=1800; a7,a5=1800; f8,e8=1400; d6,d5=1500

**Note:** Given the scores available above, the highest possible score is 2530, and the lowest possible score given all correct, but worse possible answers, is 1460.

Comment: Just curious, how much did you score?

Comment: @Binoj Antony: I didn't, I don't play chess... :-)

Comment: got 1575, where does that place me? :-)

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou: Not sure, sounds like a question to post, that being, "[Based on ELO rating, what percentile am I in?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/414/based-on-elo-rating-what-percentile-am-i-in)"

Comment: Even though I know myself to score poorly at such tests, this offset my by some 400 points…

Comment: Be careful, the scoring is jacked.  I'm getting too many points for blatantly illegal moves.

Answer (score 5):

[chesstempo.com](http://chesstempo.com)'s tactics/endgame problems (which give you a rating) are probably just as good an estimate as anything else. They might be a bit under or over, but all other assessments will suffer similarly.

Similarly, playing on any of the online services (fics/icc are probably closest to reality) will give you a rating. Those are typically a bit inflated compared to FIDE or USCF.

Comment: The USCF's ratings are also inflated compared to FIDE's.

Comment: Yeah. In tournaments don't they have you add 100 to FIDE for pairings (if you don't have a USCF rating)?

Answer (score 0):

Lucas Chess gives you a choice between playing for a "Lucas Elo" starting at 0 or a "Tourney Elo" starting at 1600.  It includes 40 odd engines which have been handicapped or are rated between 600-3000, so you can find opponents near your level.

You could download the Shredder Classic 4 demo from the Shredderchess web site, and use it for free for one month.  The Shredder Classic engine is weaker than the real Shredder, but the interface tracks your rating I believe.