# How do I get my FIDE percentile?

Tags: rating

How do I get the percentile rating?

This is the rank:

World (all players):    97112
World (active players): 45540

How many players are there in the world that are members of FIDE?

Comment: Related to http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/414/based-on-elo-rating-what-percentile-am-i-in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Based on Elo rating, what percentile am I in?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/414/based-on-elo-rating-what-percentile-am-i-in)   Specifically, [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1459/26335).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://www.quora.com/How-many-active-chess-players-are-there-in-the-world) on quora.com, there are ~486,000 players as of January 2015.  (They reference a FIDE rating list [here](http://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml).)  Not an exact number, but most likely close enough for percentile purposes.

If you're not sure how to calculate a percentile rating, I found [this question](http://study.com/academy/lesson/percentile-rank-in-statistics-definition-formula-quiz.html), which gives the following formula:

```
R = P / 100 (N + 1)
```

... where R represents the rank order of the score, P represents the percentile rank, and N represents the number of scores.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like there is half million people on the FIDE list. If I am around 50.000, that means I am around 90%, inside the top 10%.